# Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 72

Tags: java, path, writer

can someone help me with this one, im having a error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 72: D:/Users/cleyeza/Desktop/document/SEC_DOC_SUBMISSION_REPORT_2020-10-0709:54:27+0800.csv
```

and this is my code

```
        String directoryPath = AppConfig.OUTPUT_PATH.value();
        File dir = new File(directoryPath);
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        
        Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(directoryPath
                +"/" +filename+".csv"));
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I think its referring to the first : in SEC_DOC_SUBMISSION_REPORT_2020-10-0709:54:27+0800.csv If you're using windows, file names can't have :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the colons from your filename `SEC_DOC_SUBMISSION_REPORT_2020-10-0709:54:27+0800.csv`. It is a reserved character on Windows and you are not allowed to use any reserved character while naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.
Checkout the [Windows Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)